# How big does a 2D maze need to be to take two centuries to fully map it?

Tags: flora, dungeons

I was reading [a question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/84040/silica-aerogel-maze) and had a follow-up question with a story idea that I'd like to develop more fully.

The idea is a HUGE maze, thousands (or more) of square miles, that has small clearings created in it with magical happenings within them. It will have multiple biomes, but the main character is a "Cartographer" in that he makes maps for different paths through the maze to various communities that have developed in it.

The maze itself is composed of normal hedges with regenerative growing magic, and cannot be cut down or crossed on top of. The hedge will either grow in height or will continue to grow as it's being cut at a rate never allowing any gap at all to open. The setting is in the mid-1500's in terms of technology, and magic-tech fusion devices exist. There should be enough space in the maze to house at least 5 cities that can house 35000 people each, and numerous smaller cities/towns in smaller clearings. I want to stress that the maze **needs to take centuries to fully map**.

The gist of the story is that he finds a community, and falls in love with a fellow "cartographer", and loses her for years within the maze. I won't spoil the story and ending just in case, but I came on a bit of a scale question that I'm not sure I have the knowledge to answer.

**How big would this maze have to be to not only house actual villages with farms and such, but also that numerous people could feasibly make a living mapping the maze?**

Comment: I think the question is ill-conditioned. You have 5 cities with 175,000  people total; given 16th century tech you will need about 1,000,000 farmers to feed them. You have professional mappers; this means that the cities interact and trade, otherwise why bother. That's at most a mid-sized European country, definitely not larger than 200,000 sq.km. How can they lose track of one another? They can always send letters [poste-restante](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poste_restante) to the tavern in the city where they met. They must somehow correspond with the academy or guild which pays them.

Comment: A more useful plot device would be if the mazes periodically changed, this would require constant remapping and allow for people or whole communities to be lost.

Comment: Forget the fusion devices, you have literally unlimited and readily available wood from the hedges.

Comment: [Related](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/76389/why-cant-a-ladder-go-to-the-top-of-the-wall)

Comment: I think this can be answered by finding out how much farmland per capita is required.  Everything else is small in comparison.  Maybe you have *clearings* large enough for farmland and pastures, so it's just like a village with natural barriers (e.g. a valley) but yiu only care about the maze if you venture away.

Comment: @AlexP They're paid by selling the maps they've drawn to the towns they meet. There is no cartography guild that pays them, and the maps are primarily sold to merchants looking to trade surplus supplies. They aren't fusion as in "cold fusion", but rather fusion as in lanterns that hold magical light sources, and things of that nature.

Comment: @JDługosz That's the idea, almost like a "world maze" if you forgive the term, but I'd like to not encompass the world to provide a plot device later on. Rather than covering the whole world, it just holds all of the *main characters*, and there's the rest of the planet outside of it.

Comment: Why would cartographers be in constant demand? Once a path between two villages is charted, any scribe can copy the map, putting cartographers out of business. Merchants would just start planting signs like "This way to Merrytown".

Comment: *"There is no cartography guild"* -- sure there is, otherwise the entire effort of map making is wasted. Cartographers are only useful if their individual contributions are integrated. For example, Ptolemy did not actually have to travel the world to make his famous atlas. Or are the inhabitants of this world supposed to be very very silly?

Comment: @Alexander I see them more like pioneers(?) in this context. Whereas normal cartographers just make maps, these "cartographers" explore the new places that haven't been explored as of yet; a medieval Star Trek if you will. It's not that there's not signs being put up, its that these areas haven't even been explored and they are charting these new territories.

Comment: @AlexP, how do you figure that 175,000 people require 1,000,000 farmers?  Or is that 5 x 175,000 people?  Either way, you don't need near that many farmers.  Much of the problem with medieval-age farming requiring large numbers of laborers wasn't about the productivity, but rather a combination of land use planning and "what to do with all these people".  In a free market society where land for farming is available for the taking (within limits), a single farmer can provide for a number of non-farmers.

Comment: @J.D.Ray: According to the question this is a mid-16th century world. Villages are essentially autarkic entities, trading only their small surplus and avoiding buying things as far as possible. You are right, you don't need that many "farmers" properly, but you need that many "villagers". That's simply how the demographics of the late medieval / renaissance world actually was. If anything, 20% urbanised population is optimistic.

Comment: For the sake of your story writing you don't need to know exactly how big the maze is, do you? It sounds as if the characters in your story will never know. Adding too much information can distract the reader.

Comment: @LioElbammalf Actually, that's a large plot point in it. The character finds the edge, and it forces him to change his perspective to a different scale in order to see actually how big it is. In order for HIM to do that though, *I* need to be able to.

Comment: @JoshKing - If the mazes kept changing, it might discourage the attempt altogether unless the need was very pressing - and the mapping would never be done.  Maybe they change periodically or predictably (say, with the seasons, or with the life cycles of certain plants, so that some paths become impassible at certain times and open up at others) so that extra time would be needed to map each cycle of changes, to get that final mapping back in the realm of possible but taking very long.

Comment: @AlexP, I understand your point, however the OP said that the world was [sixteenth century] as far as technology goes, not sociology or governance model.  I think it's a key point, and something Anoplexian will have to decide in the course of telling the story, whether or not it actually comes up directly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- Say a normal path through the maze is 3 metres wide. The hedges on each side are 1 metre wide. That means a square kilometre could have 250 kilometres of paths. I'm ignoring the possibility of cutting corners on the way through an interection.
- If supplies are not an issue, a wanderer might make 50 km a day. Five days to walk the paths of one square kilometre. 73 square kilometres per year, 7,300 square kilometres per century, 36,500 square kilometres for five centuries.

That would be a square roughly 190 km to a side, or a circle with roughly 220 km diameter. However, you should note some assumptions here ...

- I assumed that the wanderer never has to backtrack and walk the same path twice because it is a dead end.
- I assumed that the wanderer doesn't have to return to base to gather new supplies.
- I did not account for the mapping process, which will slow the wanderer.
- For that matter, he or she is immortal and doesn't take any vacations.
- On the other hand, the towns will have to be surrounded by fields and forests. This reduces the number of pathways in the maze.
- There is more than one cartographer.

---

*Follow-up:* Combining the work of several cartographers is going to keep them busy for a *long* time. Just imagine: The first cartographer followed the path south-east from the village gate for 1,000 paces, then turned sharply west for 650 paces until he reached an intersection 100 paces in diameter. The second cartographer followed the path south-west from the village gate for 1,000 paces, then turned sharply east until he reached an intersection 100 paces in diameter. Were they on the same intersection?

Comment: Technically, if you move until the very end of every row, it will be 251km, but there will at least be half a meter at every side, allowing the cartographer to walk comfortably, and hedges on two sides, making it exactly 250498m.

Comment: Of course, if there are more than one cartographers mapping the place, you might need to scale things up a notch (and there will most likely be several *hundred* people doing it).

Comment: @Draco18s, the need to return to base and to combine the records will seriously slow things down.

Comment: @o.m. Oh sure, but I'm pretty sure the orders of magnitude here are in favor of the cartographers.

Comment: @Draco18s, see my edit.

Comment: @o.m. The question in your followup does not contain enough detail to answer yes or no.  It is *possible* for both answers to be true, you never stated how long the second cartographer walked after turning East. Nor did you make sure that both cartographers have the same pace length.  This is why we have standardized measurements, why orienteering is hard when you're untrained, and why things like *guilds* arose.

Comment: A cartographer would have to backtrack to map a previously unmapped maze.  Mathematically, in a simply-connected maze, no matter how large, backtracking should almost exactly double the length needed to walk (every space is traversed twice: To and From).  For non-simply connected maze (those with "floating sections") the floating sections would show up as large (mysterious) unmapped sections on the cartographers map, which they would then have to walk to, map (2x length), and then walk to their next destination.  So in total *at least* 2x the actual length.

Comment: I am assuming that the cartographer is using the most mathematically efficient method of mapping a simply-connected maze.

Comment: Multiple Cartographers:  If they work systematically, *as a team*, , it should not take exceptionally more work-hours for multiple cartographers than for a single one.  Say 3X instead of the optimal 2X.   In fact, using the right methodology, a mere loose association of cartographers, such as a Guild could accomplish this.  (I can describe the technique, if requested)